# Могу ли я привести без всяких опасений uint16_t к int?

Tags: c, c++

У меня в задаче необходимо привести переменную типа `uint16_t` к элементу `union` либо к `int`, либо к `long`, к чему лучше? Могу ли я сделать приведение без всяких опасений `uint16_t` к `int` или лучше делать приведение к `uint16_t` к `long`?  И вообще какие опасности в приведениях `unsigned` и `signed` (насколько я знаю `signed` везде по умолчанию).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Привести, конечно, можно. Все равно к чему, поскольку max (uint16_t) < max (int). Ведь int  в современных платформах занимает 32 бита.

Однако, если уж совсем беспокоитесь о переносимости (а вдруг попадется платформа, где int 16-битный!), то тогда long. Хотя в настоящее время это большая редкость (может, только какие-нибудь встроенные устройства).

**P.S.** В заголовочном файле limits.h есть константа WORD_BIT, которая определяет число битов в int. (Для пользования ею в Линуксе нужно определить макрос _XOPEN_SOURCE). Используя ее, можно, определить, к какому типу лучше приводить uint16_t

Answer (score 3):

Довольно интересный вопрос. По скольку языком, жестко не определяется разрядность типов, однозначно сказать, что к инту привести можно наверное нельзя, но не помню что бы где либо крестовый int был меньше чем 16 битный. Если приводить без знаковое целое к знаковому - с учетом того что у них одинаковая разрядность, можете просто получить отрицательное число, и можете просто потом это учитывать в дальнейшем. Но было бы конечно разумнее и надежнее приводить к знаковому с большей разрядностью. Т.е. мой выбор long. По поводу union - каким образом Вы хотите это делать? Хранить в нем две переменные, которые в сумме дают исходное?)